# Set parent account id to null, when removing child

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistence, entitymanager

i've got the following problem:

I've got class Parent and class Child

Parent can have a child (but can also exist without one), and child must have it's parent.

I want to achieve the following scenario:

Delete child so parent doesn't have this child anymore (e.g. child is set to null in parent class)

Is it about cascadeType or something else? And how can i achieve it?

```
import ...
@Table(name = "childtable")
public class Child{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    @SequenceGenerator(...)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    ... some fields ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "childrenSomething", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Parent parent;
    ...
}

import ...
@Entity
@Table(name = "parenttable")
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String ID;

    ... some fields ...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name="childID", nullable = true, referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    Child childrenSomething;


}
```

Comment: How you are making the deletion and what you are obtaining ?

Comment: Add `orphanRemoval = true` to your OneToOne annotation on `childrenSomething`, and use `parent.setChildrenSomething(null)`. Or set it to null, and delete the child explicitly. What have you tried, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: i'm gonna check that option with orphanRemoval... so basically if i set in the parent the orphan removal na true, and then after i set in the parent the child to null... then the child should remove itself?